# richfaces calendar today

Tags: date, calendar, richfaces

I would like to know how can I set in a richfaces calendar other day than the default one.

I want this because timezones comes to play and, if another timezone than the server's one should be used, it might be another "today" selected in calendar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the defaultTime attribute

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html

The "defaultTime" attribute to set the default time value for the current date in two cases:

- If time is not set
- If another date is selected and the value of the "resetTimeOnDateSelect" attribute is set to "true"

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is to manage the "today" from back-end.

If you have a a backing bean that gets the correct time you can just bind the rich:calendar value to the backing bean Date attribute.

**Backing bean**

```
Class MyBackingBean{
  SomeUtil someUtil;
  Date today;
  @Create
  public void init(){
    today = someUtil.getCurrentTime();
  }
  public Date getToday(){ return today;}
}
```

**Html**

```
<rich:calendar 
    id="todayDate" 
    value="#{myBackingBean.today}"></rich:calendar>
```